# How do I file tickets with Trac on code.ros.org?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know how to file tickets with [ROS Trac](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/). My issue is that I don't know how to sign up for an account. I went to [ROS code](https://code.ros.org/gf/) site, and it tells me to go to the [ROS Tickets Wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Tickets) which tells me to go back to [ROS code](https://code.ros.org/gf/), which quickly becomes circular. I have an account for editing wiki pages for ros.org and (obviously) for [ROS Answers](http://answers.ros.org/questions/?start_over=true), but when I try to use either of those logins for [ROS Trac](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/) I am not successful. Is there a page where I can sign up for Trac? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11087/how-do-i-file-tickets-with-trac-on-code.ros.org?/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I recall correctly, register on https://code.ros.org/gf/ (see link at top right). That registration will then be propagated to any Trac instance managed by gForge (including ros, ros-pkg, wg-ros-pkg, etc).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-09-01**:
That's it. Not sure why I didn't see it. Thanks.